# How do I remove the battery icon from top bar?

Tags: unity, indicator

I just discovered Ubuntu a few days ago and now upgraded to 11.10.

For the battery, I don't need it at all. I have no reason to give and does not want people to tell me "that's usefull", I think we should be able to remove it easily.

Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: Do you have built in BlueTooth hardware? I can tell you how to disable the battery icon, but if you have built in bluetooth hardware then that's another story :).

Comment: Yes, I have Bluetooth hardware, as I said in my post "I am able to open bluetooth in case I need it" ;-) Don't understand how that can interact with battery icon, but answer is "Yes".

Comment: @Proete162: It has nothing to do with the battery icon, I just wanted to tackle both together. I'll get you an answer later tonight or tomorrow :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove the battery icon by removing the `indicator-power` package. You can do this by searching for it in the software center, or by executing this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-power
```

Then logging out and back in.

Comment: Thank a lot for you help formatting my question and your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**The following answer hides the bluetooth indicator. If you want to hide / disable power indicator, follow this [First Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65751/how-do-i-remove-the-battery-icon-from-top-bar#65879)**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and paste the following line:

```
gksu nautilus /etc/xdg/autostart
```

Search for bluetooth-applet.desktop and bluetooth-applet-unity.desktop files and delete them (I recommend you to backup them first).

Restart and that's all.

Comment: How is this answer related to the question? The question is explicitly asking about removing the battery icon and the answer is about removing the bluetooth from the panel.

Comment: I think the question was about battery and bluetooth, but was edited just to be for battery indicator... I’ll edit the answer to clarify. Thank you!

Comment: Good answer. not always remove == uninstall.